# Ubuntu keeps freezing (regardless of version)

Tags: usb-installation

Recently, I started learning to use Ubuntu. I downloaded the latest version (16.04.1 LTS), and installed it on my PC using a USB stick. (Note: Ubuntu is the only OS currently installed on my PC). It was working fine for about half an hour.

After that, I tried going to my system settings, to change a few things. But suddenly, the screen froze, and got distorted (the screen image broke, basically. It looked like static on a TV).

I rebooted my PC, and I still keep getting the problem quite often.(Not just for system settings, but almost any application I open causes this to happen) I downgraded to 14.04.4, but that also didn't fix it.

What could the problem be? My PC has 2GB of RAM, and 160GB free space on the hard drive.

Comment: Try to install LXDE which is much lighter than unity. See if still you face with problem

Comment: I installed LXDE and tried using it. But, the problem is still there. The same thing happened even while using LXDE :(

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue with systems with minimal RAM. If you don't upgrade the RAM try changing the shell to a system such as Gnome.

```
apt-get install gnome-shell
```

using the stock Ubuntu shell does become graphic intense at times.

Comment: Hi, Are you referring to using a different desktop environment which takes less RAM ?

Answer (score 0):

> the screen image broke, basically. It looked like static on a TV

This could be a hardware error, graphic card with bad soldering or something else wrong with it.

Try with another graphic card if possible to see if that was the problem.

You described that you reinstalled the os several times and different distributions i don't this its os/software relaterad issue.

It can also be a bad RAM memory or motherboard but you got to start somewhere.